# How to redirect to different intent handler in ASK-SDK v2 Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

How can one redirect to a different intent handler in the Alexa Skills Kit SDK v2?

Hope this helps. It took too long for me to figure out.

In the first SDK, one could do `this.emit("IntentName")`
 or `this.emitWithState("IntentName")`.

This is no longer and option in the new SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SDK v2, use:

```
return fooHandler.handle(handlerInput)
```

You pass the handlerInput and session attributes to chosen handler.